# Using s3 in a healthcare application, private links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, amazon-s3, privacy

We develop a rails-based healthcare application.  What is the best way to configure our s3 implementation so that only the authenticated user has access to the image?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [**Documentation**](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSRubySDK/latest/AWS/S3/Bucket.html),you should use one of **Amazon's "canned" ACLs**.

Amazon accepts the following canned ACLs:

```
:private
:public_read
:public_read_write
:authenticated_read
:bucket_owner_read
:bucket_owner_full_control
```

You can specify a the ACL at bucket creation or later update a bucket.

```
# at create time, defaults to :private when not specified
bucket = s3.buckets.create('name', :acl => :public_read)

# replacing an existing bucket ACL
bucket.acl = :private
```

Answer (score 0):

Wanted to post an updated answer to this question, as the S3 API has changed (slightly) since 2015. Here's a link to the [updated ACL section](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/acl-overview.html#setting-acls) of the S3 Docs. Further, the above answer reflects the use of the Ruby SDK, which not everyone uses.

Canned ACL's are predefined grants supported by S3 that have specific grantees and permissions in place. Canned ACL's can be sent via the SDK, as demonstrated in the above answer, or in an HTTP request by using the `x-amz-acl` request header for new resources, or with the request header or body for existing resources.

The canned ACL's are as follows. Unless otherwise specified, the bucket owner has `FULL_CONTROL` in addition to the other permissions listed:

- private: No other user is granted access (default)
- public-read: AllUsers group gets `READ` access
- public-read-write: AllUsers group gets `READ` and `WRITE` access (not recommended)
- aws-exec-read: Amazon EC2 gets `READ` access to `GET` an Amazon Machine Image (bundle)
- authenticated-read: AuthenticatedUsers group gets `READ` access
- bucket-owner-read: Bucket owner gets `READ` access. Ignored when creating a bucket
- bucket-owner-full-control: Both object and bucket owner get `FULL_CONTROL` over object. Ignored when creating a bucket
- log-delivery-write: LogDelivery group gets `WRITE` and `READ_ACP` permissions

*Also noted in the docs: you can specify only one canned ACL in your request*